# Creating login for client / customer that will take them to customized part of site

Tags: login

I am not a programmer and rely on products such as wix, weebly, and wordpress to "cheat" by drag and dropping what I need. I am trying to build a site which will mostly have informational pages but I also need the ability for clients to be able to login and submit/change forms as well as upload documents. Thanks to sites such as the ones mentioned above I am able to setup the informational site and have a log in - but I need a log in where it will direct each individual to a "personal page" where they can edit their forms and upload more documents. Any ideas? Is there perhaps an html embed code or plugin of some sort that could do this?

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 0):

There is a individual personal page, the user profile. I don't know about the functionality you are talking about, but you can use the [`login_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) hook to redirect users after logging in. To get the URL needed we use the [`get_edit_profile_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_edit_profile_url/), which returns the link to before mentioned user profile.

```
add_action( 'login_redirect', 'wpse194827_redirect_to_user_profile', 10, 3 );
function wpse194827_redirect_to_user_profile( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
  return get_edit_profile_url();
}
```